# Drag and drop for dynamically added editText

Tags: android, dynamic, drag-and-drop, android-edittext

I have a button that when clicked adds a new editText. These dynamically added editTexts must be ebable to be dragged and dropped any where on the screen. But when the button is clicked a editText is added but nothing can be typed into. It still can be dragged and dropped anywhere
Now when I click the button to add another editText still the same; can't type in it but when dragged and dropped the previous edittext dissappears.
This keeps on happening. But when I tried with textViews instead of editTexts it worked fine.

This is how it worked for textview and i want the similar with editTexts

[VIDEO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwrhOOD5lzWOMl9aY1ZwdmUtRlk/view?usp=drivesdk)

**My MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

RelativeLayout dropLayout;
LayoutParams params;
Button addEdittextBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    dropLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ondraglayout);  
    dropLayout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    addEdittextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addET);

    addEdittextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                EditText et = new EditText (MainActivity.this);
                et.setText("DRAG ME");
                dropLayout.addView(et,);
                et.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
            }


        });

    }

}
```

**MyTouchListener Class**

```
public class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {

            ClipData dragdata = ClipData.newPlainText("","");

            View.DragShadowBuilder shdwbldr = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);

            v.startDrag(dragdata, shdwbldr, v, 0);
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            return true;
    }


}
```

**mydraglistener class**

```
public class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener
{

private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
{
    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();


    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();  
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
            x=  (int) event.getX();
            y =  (int) event.getY();
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();
            params.leftMargin = x;
            params.topMargin = y;

            view.setLayoutParams(params);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            break;
        default: break;
    }
    return true;
}


}
```

Comment: have you tried to switch off focus for editview?